# Is Ubuntu 23.04 compatible with Dell Precision 3520

Tags: dell, compatibility, 23.04

Is Ubuntu 23.04  compatible with Dell Precision 3520 (notebook)?

NVIDIA QUADRO M620 - Core i7-7820HQ @ 2,9 GHz - 16GB RAM - 1000GB SSD - FHD (1920x1080)
15,6 inches

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/certified/laptops

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483117/is-ubuntu-23-04-compatible-with-dell-precision-3520# My 3510 also installed without any changes in UEFI settings. Many have had to change to AHCI with older installs or older systems. Make sure Windows fast start up & bitlocker are off. Make sure UEFI and SSD firmware are latest versions. Be sure to boot installer in UEFI mode & install restricted extras to get nVidia driver installed as part of install.

Comment: I'm going to make Windows disappear from that notebook before I install Ubuntu. I'm a not computer savy. What do you mean by "Make sure UEFI and SSD firmware are latest versions."?